# 2x Windows Server for 2 labs in different parts of a building - what kind of failover to use

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, failover

I have two servers and two labs in different parts of the building with Hyper-V 2019 with VMs for Windows Server Standard (2012 R2, will be upgrading in a few years). I want to:

- configure ServerA for Lab1 and ServerB for Lab2 (I don't need help with this part)
- set the other server (A for 2 and B for 1) to be a failover in case of any problems
- sync the data user data - it may happen at night (the teachers and students will usually work in only one lab at any particular day)

I don't have much experience with multiple servers. What would be the best method to do it?

- a cluster?
- two different DC's pointing at each other?
- something different?

Comment: What is your recovery time objective? Complexity and cost are quite different for restoring last night's backup on a cold server, versus something faster.

Comment: In case of a fault one server will be able to handle both even for a few days.

Comment: 2N capacity is a different question. How long can the organization wait between "oops A is gone" to "B is also running A's workload" ?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple setup I'd set up 2 DCs with [DFS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dfs/distributed-file-system) to sync files.
A cluster is overkill for most lab scenarios and a bit to fiddly for my taste.

The set up should look like this for simplicity:

All clients should have their own DC as first DNS and the others LAB as their second.

For file access you can either point them at the DFS Share or if you want point them at their own DC. The latter would need to be changed (manually or scripted) if a Server fails.